# react-native android: TextInput briefly ignores value prop

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

This is on android with react-native v0.55.4.

```
<TextInput
  value="should always be this value"
/>
```

When I am typing inside this TextInput, the text will briefly update with whatever new text I enter, before going back to showing "should always be this value".

For example, if I type 'X', the text will briefly update to "should always be this valueX", before returning back to "should always be this value", creating a jitter inside the TextInput.

edit: the docs addressed this issue: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#value

Comment: Can you provide a bit more code, perhaps? do you have any state that you use as value?

Answer (score 0):

Based on just that short codesnippet, you need to set value to a state property.

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
   textInput: 'Should always be this value'
 }
}
```

And your text input

```
<TextInput
 value={this.state.textInput}
 onChangeText={text => this.setState({ textInput: text }) }
/>
```

Here is some [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the docs addressed my problem.   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#value